# Changing font size of code in lhs2tex

Tags: fontsize, literate-programming, lhs2tex

I am a LaTeX / Haskell newbie and this question involves `lhs2tex`. Please let me know if I am posting on the wrong forum. I am writing a report in which I have fragments like:

```
\begin{figure}  
\begin{spec}  
fib n = case n of  
    0 -> 1  
    1 -> 1  
    _ -> fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)  
\end{spec}  
\caption{Simple recursive function to calculate the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number}  
\label{fib01}  
\end{figure}
```

The report is preprocessed `with lhs2tex`. Since some of the other examples are a lot longer than this one, I want to reduce the font size only for the `code` and `spec` blocks. Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: And these `spec` and `code` environments are defined by a package, or did you define them?

Answer (score 3):

Don't change the file which is produced by `lhs2tex`! Then you have to change it every time you run `lhs2tex`. Put

```
\renewcommand{\hscodestyle}{\small}
```

in the `.lhs` file instead.

Comment: I'd prefer to just upvote or comment on the answers, but can't because I just registered and lack the reputation to do so. I am the author of `lhs2tex` and want to express strong support for the answer given by Bengt. That's the right way to do it. Generally, **never** edit generated files, and in particular, don't edit the output of `lhs2tex`.

Answer (score 0):

you can define the `\hscodestyle` command in the resulting .tex to be whatever you want for formatting. 
Open the output .tex that lhs2tex produces, and change the line that looks like this:

```
\newcommand{\hscodestyle}{}
```

to

```
\newcommand{\hscodestyle}{\small}
```

Comment: No problem! If this answer was ok, then please accept it, so other people who come upon your question can easily find it as well. Cheers!